# Android Action Bar Logo Home Button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm currently developing an android application and i'm looking to make the logo on the left of the action bar a menu button. I have enabled the logo using the code

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

from my research I should be able to make this a a menu button by using the code

```
if (id == R.id.home) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

in `onOptionsItemSelected` but this is not working for me.

Is there a way to change or find the correct ID for this logo as im starting to think `R.id.home` is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think with enabling your home button with

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and then

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case android.R.id.home:
    //fire intent or whatever you require.. do over here
    return true;
default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

I think this should work fine.